# C#, Few Tasks with many sequential logic OR Many task with few sequential logic?

Tags: c#, task

I implementing on server game loop (Dealing with tick rate).

In server we will have many room. Goal is to gain highest performance. (lowest memory consumption, lowest CPU, high room availability).

However I'm decision between options.

- **Single update loop with multiple room**. (Using Tasks and Delay) This will make many logic done in sequence in a single game loop
- **Single update loop with multiple room**. (Using self managed Thread) And get each Thread run in each core.
- **Single game loop for each room**. (Using Tasks and Delay) This will make logic for each room done in concurrent.

What option should I choose and how to achieve the best performance

Comment: I doubt it would make any difference.  Processing for such rooms is trivial.   But how many rooms do you mean?  4 or 5, or 100s, or 1000s ?

Comment: As much as possible, 1000++ will be great.

Comment: Tick rate is about 15 per second :)

Comment: It sounds like zero processor load, but, I don't understand your situation.

Comment: Voting to close, the question is too broad.

Comment: It's about real-time game server. Handling as much CCU as possible.
@BrianOgden Why this is too broad? What is asked is about, How good C# manage Tasks and Thread compare to each others. And how to gain the best from them.

Comment: Why do you need "the best" if you don't even have "working" yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest the only answer here is

- You just **try all three** (and more) and test the numbers.

It is quite trivial to try the three different approaches you say.

In fact, in some systems:

- you would simply do it all three ways, and
- the system as it is running with a load, would just test which is most efficient, and change to that one

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the room task. When it is a small task and the number of rooms is large, separate threads for each room will only add overhead.

Comment: Hmm, But separate tasks doesn't mean we have multiple Threads sinces C# managed this for us. But what I doubt that does it effective than having very few threads/Tasks. :)

Comment: Yes, the number of actual processor threads will be the number of cores and it make sense to provide only 4-10 threads in a thread pool, depending on your machine. But imho a single C# task per room can be avoided. You could e.g.  segment a large task in separate fixed size chunks and each chunk is performed as a single thread by one processor core, or one cluster node code, without the need for any GC or context switches.